# How can we get top contributors for a Sharepoint site

Tags: usage-counters

Can we get the top contributors of a particular Site Collection or a Web application by any means like OOTB or c# maybe.

I looked at many blogs but did not find any substantial answers.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at contributors to a document library (pages also) these examples of querying the SharePoint usage database will be helpful:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14232/Useful-SQL-Queries-to-Analyze-and-Monitor-SharePoi

You can also view the usage logs using [Log Parser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb878032.aspx) to see which users are using the site the most. This is [easier to work with in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181537/exporting-sharepoint-usage-log-files-into-a-database-using-logparser/182361#182361).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ryan but my concern is i would not have access to the SQL Server.How about using the Change Log?